# Zend Controller Name Case Sensitivity

Tags: apache, zend-framework, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I'm using the Zend Framework to develop an application on a linux host, and for some reason when I try to go to localhost/index it gives me what looks like a standard Apache 404 error. But when I go to localhost/Index it works. I can also go to localhost/admin and it will work with no problem. For some reason it seems that my index controller doesn't want to work. How can I make it to where localhost/index works?

My .htaccess file seems fine and has the correct rewrite rules in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and tracked it back to Options MultiViews on Apache.  If you're using a vhost, check there.  If I recall, MultiViews will try to find other files with a similar name if the requested file is not found.  If it's on, try disabling it and see what happens.